# How to remove the international date line (IDL) and equator from Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

As per the title, I would like to remove the IDL and equator line from my map.  I am using the following code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var locations = [
['<p>Location 1<br/> <a href="http://example.com/location1">Click here for more info</a></p>', 64.8436, -147.7231, 1],
['<p>Location 2<br/> <a href="http://example.com/location2">Click here for more info</a></p>', 33.4500, -112.0667, 2],
['<p>Location 3<br/> <a href="http://example.com/location3">Click here for more info</a></p>', 34.0500, -118.2500, 3],
['<p>Location 4<br/> <a href="http://example.com/location4">Click here for more info</a></p>', 32.7150, -117.1625, 4],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 2,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.4328, -99.1333),
mapTypeControl: false,
scaleControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
overviewMapControl: false
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
}

</script>
```

I'm quite new to this, and any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076095/removing-or-coloring-equator-and-international-date-line-in-google-maps-api), you need to set some undocumented properties on a stylized map.  This may remove other features beyond the IDL and equator.

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 2,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.4328, -99.1333),
 mapTypeControl: false,
 scaleControl: false,
 streetViewControl: false,
 overviewMapControl: false
 });

 var mapStyle = [
      {
         featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "geometry.fill",
         stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       }
  ];
 var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle);
 map.mapTypes.set('myCustomMap', styledMap);
 map.setMapTypeId('myCustomMap');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/stevejansen/pBh6p/

Comment: It is not really *undocumented*. There is [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType). What we don't know however is what exactly falls in each feature type. But that seems to work! Good answer here.

Comment: Hi @MrUpsidown, you are correct.  Perhaps "poorly documented" is more fair.   The documentation for `geometry.fill` reads "Apply the rule to the fill of the feature's geometry."  That's pretty darn confusing to me.  I'd have a hard time translating that to "show/hide the IDL and equator features."