# How to Avoid center dotted line from google map

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

I am using Google map on page load google map starts from this location, i want avoid this red dotted line while loading google map.

Also tried to set default location for map, but every time map starts load from like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not "dotted line", it's equator

Answer (score 1):

As [Shankar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6144590/shankar) wrote you can do this via [Google Maps Styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling):

create in `raw` folder JSON file (e.g. `map_style.json`) without Equator settings (for details, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6076095/6950238) question and answers):

`map_style.json`:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  }
]
```

then apply it in `onMapReady()` callback:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.map_style));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }    
    }
}
```

and you'll got something like that:

[image: Styled map without equator line]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the elementType to geometry. Refer these official [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) and this Medium [post](https://medium.com/exploring-android/introducing-custom-map-styles-for-google-maps-be2095c38850).

You can focus particular location using

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latiude,longitude));
```